# Clearing The Contents Of A Field While Scraping Using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to clear the contents of a field on a screen which I am scraping to.
I have tried :
.SendKeys("") but this does not work. Is anybody able to help me with the correct code?

Comment: That should be:-  .SendKeys("<Clearcontents>")

Comment: .SendKeys("<Clear>") clears the whole screen. How do I clear just the field?